# AJAX request in setInterval() stops working due to other AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two AJAX requests. One of the request (`$.post(/updatechart, [...])`) is triggered repeatedly using `setInterval()`. The second one (`$.post(/updateperiod, [...])`) is triggered when an item from a dropdown-menu is chosen. Because of the second request, the first one stops working after a while, if I trigger the second one a few times. Sometimes, they both stop working. Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

**EDIT:**
stops working = request is not sent to the server anymore

**EDIT2:** Thanks to IcePickle I fixed the issue. I was not sending a response to the second AJAX request.

```
var retrieved;
var period_types = {
    week: "Expenses this week",
    month: "Expenses this month",
    year: "Expenses this year"
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        updateGraph();
    }, 1000);

    $(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
        var new_period = $(this).attr('value');
        $.post("/updateperiod", data = {period: new_period});
    });
});

function updateGraph() {
    $.post("/updatechart", function(response) {
        retrieved = response;
        drawGraph(retrieved);
    });
}

function drawGraph(response) {
    var x_axis = []
    var y_axis = []
    var data = [];
    response.db.forEach(element => {
        x_axis.push(element.amount);
        y_axis.push(element.category); 
    });
    data = [
        {
            type: 'bar',
            y: y_axis,
            x: x_axis,
            orientation: 'h',
            marker: {
                color: 'rgb(33, 40, 109)'
            }
        }
    ];
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = period_types[response.period];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *they stop working*

Comment: @Icepickle the request is not sent to the server.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information, maybe your external service is taking too long to respond. What happens when you put a console.log instruction inside updateGraph function?

Comment: @danielarend if I put a `console.log()` in `updateGraph()`, the output is shown. But when I put a `console.log()` inside the post-request function, the output is not shown. That's why I figured that the AJAX request stopped working .

Comment: @Zarif you don't see the request arriving at the server or it is even not registered as pending in your network tab in the debugger tools? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @Icepickle Thank you. I looked at the network tab and the second request was not receiving anything back. I fixed it by sending a response from the back-end. Problem solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add settings parameter on the `$.post()`, that is equal to `$.ajax()` method, where you can set the option:

```
settings: {
 "async": "false"
}
```

So you can make multiple ajax request on the page.

Comment: This should be avoided.  Not only is this deprecated in jQuery, but browsers themselves are deprecating synchronous web requests.